# How can I send a private message to someone on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, private-messaging

I cannot find a way of private messaging SO members, is it possible?

Comment: Why was this migrated?

Comment: Yea.. I see the original post too in the revisons... Why **was** this migrated?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be migrated? Throwing some random code copy/pasted from Google into a question to get around quality filters doesn't make it a programming question.

Answer (score 7):

You can't

You can create a chatroom with someone if you have enough reputation.

Comment: But how much reputation is required and, when you have it, how do you creat a chatroom with someone?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  If there is something you should be discussing on the site, you can do so publicly.  Perhaps it makes sense to go to a chatroom to speak to that user?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Stack overflow is a Q&A site, not a social network.

Use @Username in a comment if you want to reply to someone already participating in the comment thread. Commenting on someone's post will also notify them.